# Angular index.html cached for some users after base URL changed

Tags: angular, azure, google-chrome, caching

Here is the story of a version upgrade **blocker**.

We have an Angular dashboard served by an "Azure App Service Web App".
The dashboard communicates with a NodeJS backend, also served by another Azure instance.

There was until now 2 releases deployed.
The first dashboard release was accessible through a single URL and contained no internal routes. Let's name the URL "domain.com"
The second dashboard release added a base-href change to the main URL. And added also internal
routes. Let's name the result URL "domain.com/base-href/internal-page"

**The problem:**
When we deployed the release 3, some users discovered that opening the main URL "domain.com" they see the index.html from release 2, and opening the same URL "domain.com" on another tab they get the index.html from release 3. And so on alternatively...

**The verifications we did:**
There is no service in that Angular dashboard.
There is no cache configuration set on Azure. To confirm that, we put off completely the Azure service, and the users concerned still saw the index.html (loaded from disk cache) from release 2.

What could we do now to be as sure as possible that on release 3, there won't be at all (if possible) users seeing the index.html from release 2, loaded from disk cache. If it's not possible, how can we prevent the index.html from release 3 to be cached by Chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `cache-control` header [you can set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) specifically for this purpose. Setting it to `no-store` should prevent any browser from caching the file in any way, though `no-cache` may be sufficient for your purposes. Technically if a browser decides to ignore this header there's not much you can do, but pretty much any modern browser, including Chrome, should respect it.